# Grouping and merging two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have been banging my head around this one for some time now and can't get my head around it...

I have two Pandas Dataframes `df1` and `df2` which contains information that I want to summarize neatly into one.

So far, I have used an aggregate function to summarize each of these as follows:

```
aggregation = {'A' : {'a' : 'mean'}, 'B' : {'b' : 'mean'}, 'C' : {'c' : 'sum'}}

>> df1.groupby(by=['LEVEL_1']).agg(aggregation)

            A      B      C
            a      b      c
LEVEL_1     
lvl_a       1.0    2.0    3.0
lvl_b       4.0    5.0    6.0
lvl_c       7.0    8.0    9.0
```

Same for my other DataFrame

```
>> df2.groupby(by=['LEVEL_1']).agg(aggregation)

            A      B      C
            a      b      c
LEVEL_1     
lvl_a       10.0   11.0   12.0
lvl_b       13.0   14.0   15.0
lvl_c       16.0   17.0   18.0
```

Now, I would like to combine these two into one, total, DataFrame where my columns are grouped into the two "information universes", with an additional row `totals`, which is the mean of all the rows, per column, like so:

```
            a             b            c
            df1    df2    df1   df2    df1   df2
LEVEL_1     
lvl_a       1.0    10.0   2.0   11.0   3.0    12.0
lvl_b       4.0    13.0   5.0   14.0   6.0    15.0
lvl_c       7.0    16.0   8.0   17.0   9.0    18.0
totals      4.0    13.0   5.0   14.0   6.0    15.0
```

There is, most likely, a supereasy way to do this, but I have not figured it out...

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `concat`+`droplevel`+`swaplevel`

```
s=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,keys=['df1','df2'])
s.columns=s.columns.droplevel(1)

s=s.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
s
Out[473]: 
         a         b         c     
       df1  df2  df1  df2  df1  df2
lvl_a  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  3.0
lvl_b  4.0  4.0  5.0  5.0  6.0  6.0
lvl_c  7.0  7.0  8.0  8.0  9.0  9.0
```

Update

```
pd.concat([s,s.sum().to_frame('total').T])
Out[479]: 
          a           b           c      
        df1   df2   df1   df2   df1   df2
lvl_a   1.0   1.0   2.0   2.0   3.0   3.0
lvl_b   4.0   4.0   5.0   5.0   6.0   6.0
lvl_c   7.0   7.0   8.0   8.0   9.0   9.0
total  12.0  12.0  15.0  15.0  18.0  18.0
```

Comment: Haha, that was the fastest answer so far. Thank you! Never seen the swaplevel-functionality before, but your answer works perfectly!

Comment: @gussilago yw~ :-) happy coding

Comment: While I'm at it: Is it possible to also add a "totals"-row (mean of all rows, per column) to the final dataframe :S If you an answer, I can always add it to the original question...

Comment: Much appreciated @Wen

Comment: @gussilago yw :-) happy coding